# How to Digitally Sign a Dynamically Created PDF Document Using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pdfbox

Pardon Me! I am poor in java. 
 Please Correct me wherever I am wrong and improve wherever I am poor!

I am trying to digitally sign a dynamically created pdf using PDFBox with the following program:

**Tasks in the Program:** 
(i) Creating Template PDF
(ii) Updating ByteRange, xref, startxref
(iii) Constructing Original Document for Signature Creation
(iv) Creating Detached Enveloped Digital Signature
(v) Constructing Digitally Signed PDF Document by concatenating Original Doc Part - I, Detached Signature and Original PDF Part - II

**Observations:**
(i) pdfFileOutputStream.write(documentOutputStream.toByteArray()); createsTemplate PDF Document with Visible Signature.

(ii) It Creates Some PDF Signed Document but has errors (a) invalid tokens and (b) several parser errors
 (now corrected under the abled guidance of MKL!)

**Please suggest me on the following:**

(i) How to add Signature Text in the Visible Signature on the layer2.

Thanks in Advance!

```
    package digitalsignature;

    import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.security.Signature;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder;
    import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaCertStore;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGenerator;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
    import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
    import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
    import org.bouncycastle.util.Store;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.security.KeyStore;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.cert.CertStore;
    import java.security.cert.Certificate;
    import java.security.cert.CollectionCertStoreParameters;
    import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;

    import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectForm;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceDictionary;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceStream;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SignatureOptions;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
    import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedGenerator;
    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;


    public class AffixSignature {
        String path = "D:\\reports\\";
        String onlyFileName = "";
        String pdfExtension = ".pdf";
        String pdfFileName = "";
        String pdfFilePath = "";
        String signedPdfFileName = "";
        String signedPdfFilePath = "";
        String ownerPassword = "";
        String tempSignedPdfFileName = "";
        String tempSignedPdfFilePath = "";
        String userPassword = "";
        String storePath = "resources/my.p12";
        String entryAlias = "signerCert";
        String keyStorePassword = "password";
        ByteArrayOutputStream documentOutputStream = null;
        private Certificate[] certChain;
        private static BouncyCastleProvider BC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        int offsetContentStart = 0;
        int offsetContentEnd = 0;
        int secondPartLength = 0;
        int offsetStartxrefs = 0;
        String contentString = "";
        OutputStream signedPdfFileOutputStream;
        OutputStream pdfFileOutputStream;

        public AffixSignature() {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh_mm_ss");

            onlyFileName = "Report_" + timeFormat.format(new Date());
            pdfFileName = onlyFileName + ".pdf";
            pdfFilePath = path + pdfFileName;
            File pdfFile = new File(pdfFilePath);
            pdfFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);

            signedPdfFileName = "Signed_" + onlyFileName + ".pdf";
            signedPdfFilePath = path + signedPdfFileName;
            File signedPdfFile = new File(signedPdfFilePath);
            signedPdfFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(signedPdfFile);

            String tempFileName = "Temp_Report_" + timeFormat.format(new Date());
            String tempPdfFileName = tempFileName + ".pdf";
            String tempPdfFilePath = path + tempPdfFileName;
            File tempPdfFile = new File(tempPdfFilePath);
            OutputStream tempSignedPdfFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempPdfFile);

            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);


            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
            Map<String, PDFont> fonts = new HashMap<String, PDFont>();
            fonts = new HashMap<String, PDFont>();
            fonts.put("F1", font);

//            contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
            contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
            contentStream.drawString("DIGITAL SIGNATURE TEST");
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
            document.addPage(page);

//To Affix Visible Digital Signature
            PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
            catalog.setAcroForm(acroForm);

            PDSignatureField sf = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);

            PDSignature pdSignature = new PDSignature();
            page.getAnnotations().add(sf.getWidget());
            pdSignature.setName("sign");
            pdSignature.setByteRange(new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0});
            pdSignature.setContents(new byte[4 * 1024]);
            pdSignature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
            pdSignature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            pdSignature.setName("NAME");
            pdSignature.setLocation("LOCATION");
            pdSignature.setReason("SECURITY");
            pdSignature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
            List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();

            sf.setSignature(pdSignature);
            sf.getWidget().setPage(page);

            COSDictionary acroFormDict = acroForm.getDictionary();
            acroFormDict.setDirect(true);
            acroFormDict.setInt(COSName.SIG_FLAGS, 3);
            acroFormFields.add(sf);

            PDRectangle frmRect = new PDRectangle();
//            float[] frmRectParams = {lowerLeftX,lowerLeftY,upperRightX,upperRight};
//            float[] frmRectLowerLeftUpperRightCoordinates = {5f, page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 50f, 100f, page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - 5f};
            float[] frmRectLowerLeftUpperRightCoordinates = {5f, 5f, 205f, 55f};
            frmRect.setUpperRightX(frmRectLowerLeftUpperRightCoordinates[2]);
            frmRect.setUpperRightY(frmRectLowerLeftUpperRightCoordinates[3]);
            frmRect.setLowerLeftX(frmRectLowerLeftUpperRightCoordinates[0]);
            frmRect.setLowerLeftY(frmRectLowerLeftUpperRightCoordinates[1]);

            sf.getWidget().setRectangle(frmRect);

            COSArray procSetArr = new COSArray();
            procSetArr.add(COSName.getPDFName("PDF"));
            procSetArr.add(COSName.getPDFName("Text"));
            procSetArr.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageB"));
            procSetArr.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageC"));
            procSetArr.add(COSName.getPDFName("ImageI"));

            String signImageFilePath = "resources/sign.JPG";
            File signImageFile = new File(signImageFilePath);
            InputStream signImageStream = new FileInputStream(signImageFile);
            PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(document, signImageStream);

            PDResources holderFormResources = new PDResources();
            PDStream holderFormStream = new PDStream(document);
            PDXObjectForm holderForm = new PDXObjectForm(holderFormStream);
            holderForm.setResources(holderFormResources);
            holderForm.setBBox(frmRect);
            holderForm.setFormType(1);

            PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
            appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
            PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(holderForm.getCOSStream());
            appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
            sf.getWidget().setAppearance(appearance);
            acroFormDict.setItem(COSName.DR, holderFormResources.getCOSDictionary());

            PDResources innerFormResources = new PDResources();
            PDStream innerFormStream = new PDStream(document);
            PDXObjectForm innerForm = new PDXObjectForm(innerFormStream);
            innerForm.setResources(innerFormResources);
            innerForm.setBBox(frmRect);
            innerForm.setFormType(1);

            String innerFormName = holderFormResources.addXObject(innerForm, "FRM");

            PDResources imageFormResources = new PDResources();
            PDStream imageFormStream = new PDStream(document);
            PDXObjectForm imageForm = new PDXObjectForm(imageFormStream);
            imageForm.setResources(imageFormResources);
            byte[] AffineTransformParams = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
            AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform(AffineTransformParams[0], AffineTransformParams[1], AffineTransformParams[2], AffineTransformParams[3], AffineTransformParams[4], AffineTransformParams[5]);
            imageForm.setMatrix(affineTransform);
            imageForm.setBBox(frmRect);
            imageForm.setFormType(1);

            String imageFormName = innerFormResources.addXObject(imageForm, "n");
            String imageName = imageFormResources.addXObject(img, "img");

            innerForm.getResources().getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, procSetArr);
            page.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, procSetArr);
            innerFormResources.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, procSetArr);
            imageFormResources.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, procSetArr);
            holderFormResources.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.PROC_SET, procSetArr);

            String holderFormComment = "q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /" + innerFormName + " Do Q \n";
            String innerFormComment = "q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /" + imageFormName + " Do Q\n";
            String imgFormComment = "q " + 100 + " 0 0 50 0 0 cm /" + imageName + " Do Q\n";

            appendRawCommands(holderFormStream.createOutputStream(), holderFormComment);
            appendRawCommands(innerFormStream.createOutputStream(), innerFormComment);
            appendRawCommands(imageFormStream.createOutputStream(), imgFormComment);

            documentOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            document.save(documentOutputStream);
            document.close();
            tempSignedPdfFileOutputStream.write(documentOutputStream.toByteArray());
            generateSignedPdf();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void appendRawCommands(OutputStream os, String commands) throws IOException {
        os.write(commands.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        os.close();
    }

    public void generateSignedPdf() {
        try {
            //Find the Initial Byte Range Offsets
            String docString = new String(documentOutputStream.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1");
            offsetContentStart = (documentOutputStream.toString().indexOf("Contents <") + 10 - 1);
            offsetContentEnd = (documentOutputStream.toString().indexOf("000000>") + 7);
            secondPartLength = (documentOutputStream.size() - documentOutputStream.toString().indexOf("000000>") - 7);
            //Calculate the Updated ByteRange
            String initByteRange = "";
            if (docString.indexOf("/ByteRange [0 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000]") > 0) {
                initByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 1000000000 1000000000 1000000000]";
            } else if (docString.indexOf("/ByteRange [0 0 0 0]") > 0) {
                initByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 0 0 0]";
            } else {
                System.out.println("No /ByteRange Token is Found!");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            String interimByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 " + offsetContentStart + " " + offsetContentEnd + " " + secondPartLength + "]";
            int byteRangeLengthDifference = interimByteRange.length() - initByteRange.length();
            offsetContentStart = offsetContentStart + byteRangeLengthDifference;
            offsetContentEnd = offsetContentEnd + byteRangeLengthDifference;
            String finalByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 " + offsetContentStart + " " + offsetContentEnd + " " + secondPartLength + "]";
            byteRangeLengthDifference += interimByteRange.length() - finalByteRange.length();
            //Replace the ByteRange
            docString = docString.replace(initByteRange, finalByteRange);

            //Update xref Table
            int xrefOffset = docString.indexOf("xref");
            int startObjOffset = docString.indexOf("0000000000 65535 f") + "0000000000 65535 f".length() + 1;
            int trailerOffset = docString.indexOf("trailer") - 2;
            String initialXrefTable = docString.substring(startObjOffset, trailerOffset);
            int signObjectOffset = docString.indexOf("/Type /Sig") - 3;
            String updatedXrefTable = "";
            while (initialXrefTable.indexOf("n") > 0) {
                String currObjectRefEntry = initialXrefTable.substring(0, initialXrefTable.indexOf("n") + 1);
                String currObjectRef = currObjectRefEntry.substring(0, currObjectRefEntry.indexOf(" 00000 n"));
                int currObjectOffset = Integer.parseInt(currObjectRef.trim().replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""));
                if ((currObjectOffset + byteRangeLengthDifference) > signObjectOffset) {
                    currObjectOffset += byteRangeLengthDifference;
                    int currObjectOffsetDigitsCount = Integer.toString(currObjectOffset).length();
                    currObjectRefEntry = currObjectRefEntry.replace(currObjectRefEntry.substring(currObjectRef.length() - currObjectOffsetDigitsCount, currObjectRef.length()), Integer.toString(currObjectOffset));
                    updatedXrefTable += currObjectRefEntry;
                } else {
                    updatedXrefTable += currObjectRefEntry;
                }
                initialXrefTable = initialXrefTable.substring(initialXrefTable.indexOf("n") + 1);
            }
            //Replace with Updated xref Table
            docString = docString.substring(0, startObjOffset).concat(updatedXrefTable).concat(docString.substring(trailerOffset));

            //Update startxref
            int startxrefOffset = docString.indexOf("startxref");
            //Replace with Updated startxref
            docString = docString.substring(0, startxrefOffset).concat("startxref\n".concat(Integer.toString(xrefOffset))).concat("\n%%EOF\n");

            //Construct Original Document For Signature by Removing Temporary Enveloped Detached Signed Content(000...000)
            contentString = docString.substring(offsetContentStart + 1, offsetContentEnd - 1);
            String docFirstPart = docString.substring(0, offsetContentStart);
            String docSecondPart = docString.substring(offsetContentEnd);
            String docForSign = docFirstPart.concat(docSecondPart);

            //Generate Signature
            pdfFileOutputStream.write(docForSign.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            File keyStorefile = new File(storePath);
            InputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileInputStream(keyStorefile);
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            certChain = keyStore.getCertificateChain(entryAlias);
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(entryAlias, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
            certList = Arrays.asList(certChain);
            Store store = new JcaCertStore(certList);
//            String algorithm="SHA1WithRSA";
//            String algorithm="SHA2WithRSA";
            String algorithm = "MD5WithRSA";
            //String algorithm = "DSA";

            //Updated Sign Method
            CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(docForSign.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            /* Build the SignerInfo generator builder, that will build the generator... that will generate the SignerInformation... */
            SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoBuilder = new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(BC).build());
            //JcaContentSignerBuilder contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA2withRSA");
            JcaContentSignerBuilder contentSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(algorithm);
            contentSigner.setProvider(BC);
            SignerInfoGenerator signerInfoGenerator = signerInfoBuilder.build(contentSigner.build(privateKey), new X509CertificateHolder(certList.get(0).getEncoded()));
            generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(signerInfoGenerator);
            generator.addCertificates(store);
            CMSSignedData signedData = generator.generate(msg, false);
            String apHexEnvelopedData = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString(signedData.getEncoded()).toUpperCase();
            //Construct Content Tag Data
            contentString = apHexEnvelopedData.concat(contentString).substring(0, contentString.length());
            contentString = "<".concat(contentString).concat(">");
            //Construct Signed Document
            String signedDoc = docFirstPart.concat(contentString).concat(docSecondPart);
            //Write Signed Document to File
            signedPdfFileOutputStream.write(signedDoc.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
            signedPdfFileOutputStream.close();
            signedDoc = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error While Generating Signed Data", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AffixSignature affixSignature = new AffixSignature();
    }
}
```

Under the abled guidance of MKL, now the updated code signs the newly created document. Thanks to MKL!

Comment: *It Creates Some PDF Signed Document but has errors* - Please share this document. There is too much code to say anything without spending a considerable amount of time, but seeing a sample output may give an immediate idea what to look for.

Comment: That been asked for, I quickly scanned your code and I doubt PDFBox will be happy about your `appendRawCommands(XXXFormStream.createOutputStream(), YYY)` calls (creating output streams for the same form more than once may be an issue, and switching back and forth between the forms also); furthermore there does not seem to be a whitespace between the multiple strings you try to write to the same stream giving rise to unknown **Qq** operators. Furthermore the `appendRawCommands` uses UTF-8 which is completely non-PDF.

Comment: Your `generateSignedDocument` probably does quite a lot of damage as it assumes it can work with PDFs as if they were text files. That in general is not the case. And the actual manipulation look very questionable, too.

Comment: Please do share the PDF as binary download somewhere (e.g. public dropbox share); there are some details that simply get lost by posting PDFs as text. That been said the structure looks quite sensibly, merely the stream 8 0 references itself in its XObject resources which might make any pdf viewer through up. And you seem to have edited out more than you wanted, there are no objects 11 0 and 12 0 in your posting.

Comment: If you compare the bytes of both documents you'll find that there are many unwanted changes, at first glance especially the replacement of certain bytes by question marks. This most likely is due to your making the `byte[]` a `String` to easily operate on the document and eventually changing it back into a `byte[]` again. A quick test shows that (in case of Latin encoding) this routine changes the bytes 0x81, 0x8d, 0x8f, 0x90, and 0x9d into 0x3f (i.e. a question mark). Thus, you'll have to work with `byte` and `byte[]` operations instead of `String` operations here.

Comment: Ok, I added the answer before I saw this change. Yes, "ISO-8859-1" does not seem to break any specific bytes as the default does, but I still doubt it is a good idea. The remarks concerning the errors in the signature container and its construction still are valid.

Comment: You still use `generator.generate(msg, true);` why do you use `true` here?

Comment: Ok, now it's `false`. What is the current output? Does Adobe Reader accept it now? If not, please update your PDF sample

Comment: I added two sections to my answer below. The most important issue for you right now most likely is the *Hash value calculation issue*.

Comment: *How to add Signature Text in the Visible Signature on the layer2.* - essentially you need to register a font (e.g. named **F0**) in the `imageFormResources` and add something like `" BT /F0 12 Tf 3 3 Td (Text) Tj ET "` to `imgFormComment`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*While initially these hints were presented as comments to the original question, they now merit to be formulated as an answer:*

### Code issues

While there is too much code to review and fix without spending a considerable amount of time, and while the original absence of a sample PDF was a hindrance, a quick scan of the code revealed some issues:

- The `appendRawCommands(XXXFormStream.createOutputStream(), YYY)` calls quite likely cause problems with PDFBox: creating output streams for the same form more than once may be an issue, and also switching back and forth between the forms.
- Furthermore there does not seem to be a whitespace between the multiple strings written to the same stream giving rise to unknown **Qq** operators. Furthermore the `appendRawCommands` method uses UTF-8 which is foreign to PDF.
- The `generateSignedDocument` most likely does quite a lot of damage as it assumes it can work with PDFs as if they were text files. That in general is not the case.

### Result PDF issues

The sample result PDF eventually provided by the OP allows to pinpoint some actually realized issues:

- Comparing the bytes of both documents (Report_08_05_23.pdf and Signed_Report_08_05_23.pdf) one finds that there are many unwanted changes, at first glance especially the replacement of certain bytes by question marks. This is due to using `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()` to easily operate on the document and eventually changing it back into a `byte[]`.

  E.g. cf. the JavaDocs of `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()`

  ```
  * <p> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character
  * sequences with the default replacement string for the platform's
  * default character set. The {@linkplain java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder}
  * class should be used when more control over the decoding process is
  * required.
  ```

  Certain byte values do not represent characters in the *platform's default character set* and therefore are transformed to the [Unicode *Replacement Character*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) and in the final transformation into a `byte[]` become 0x3f (ASCII code for the question mark). This change kills compressed stream contents, both of content streams and image streams.

  To fix this, one has to work with `byte` and `byte[]` operations instead of `String` operations here.
- The stream 8 0 references itself in its XObject resources which might make any pdf viewer throw up. Please refrain from such circularity.

### Signature Container issues

The signature does not verify. Thus, it also is reviewed.

- Inspecting the signature container one can see that it is wrong: In spite of the signature being **adbe.pkcs7.detached**, the signature container embeds data. Looking at the code the reason becomes clear:

  ```
  CMSSignedData sigData = generator.generate(msg, true);
  ```

  The `true` parameter asks BC to embed the `msg` data.
- Having started to look at the signing code, another issue becomes visible: The `msg` data above are not merely a digest, they already are a signature:

  ```
  Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithm, BC);
  signature.initSign(privateKey);
  signature.update(docForSign.getBytes());
  CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(signature.sign());
  ```

which is wrong as the later created `SignerInfoGenerator` is used to create the actual signature.

**Edit:** After the issues mentioned before have been fixed or at least worked-around, the signature is still not accepted by the Adobe Reader. Thus, another look at the code and:

### Hash value calculation issue

The OP constructs this **ByteRange** value

```
String finalByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 " + offsetContentStart + " " + offsetContentEnd + " " + secondPartLength + "]";
```

and later sets

```
String docFirstPart = docString.substring(0, offsetContentStart + 1);
String docSecondPart = docString.substring(offsetContentEnd - 1);
```

The `+ 1` and `- 1` are intended to make these document parts also include the `<` and `>` enveloping the signature bytes. But the OP also uses these strings to construct the signed data:

```
String docForSign = docFirstPart.concat(docSecondPart);
```

**This is wrong**, the signed bytes do not contain the `<` and `>`. Thus, the hash value later on calculated also is wrong and Adobe Reader has good reasons to assume the document has been manipulated.

That been said, there also are other issues bound to come up every once in a while:

### Offset and length updating issues

The OP inserts the byte range to be like this:

```
String interimByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 " + offsetContentStart + " " + offsetContentEnd + " " + secondPartLength + "]";
int byteRangeLengthDifference = interimByteRange.length() - initByteRange.length();
offsetContentStart = offsetContentStart + byteRangeLengthDifference;
offsetContentEnd = offsetContentEnd + byteRangeLengthDifference;
String finalByteRange = "/ByteRange [0 " + offsetContentStart + " " + offsetContentEnd + " " + secondPartLength + "]";
byteRangeLengthDifference += interimByteRange.length() - finalByteRange.length();
//Replace the ByteRange
docString = docString.replace(initByteRange, finalByteRange);
```

Every one in a while `offsetContentStart` or `offsetContentEnd` will be slightly below some 10^n and slightly above afterwards. The line

```
byteRangeLengthDifference += interimByteRange.length() - finalByteRange.length();
```

tries to make up for this, but `finalByteRange` (which eventually is inserted into the document) still contains uncorrected values.

In a similar fashion the representation of the xref start inserted like this

```
docString = docString.substring(0, startxrefOffset).concat("startxref\n".concat(Integer.toString(xrefOffset))).concat("\n%%EOF\n");
```

may also be longer than before which makes the byte range (calculated beforehand) not cover the whole document.

Furthermore finding offsets of the relevant PDF objects using text searches of the whole document

```
offsetContentStart = (documentOutputStream.toString().indexOf("Contents <") + 10 - 1);
offsetContentEnd = (documentOutputStream.toString().indexOf("000000>") + 7);
...
int xrefOffset = docString.indexOf("xref");
...
int startxrefOffset = docString.indexOf("startxref");
```

will fail for generic documents. E.g. if there already are previous signatures in the document, quite likely the wrong indices will be identified like this.